# Missing "nearest" function for the implimentation of "k.check" function

Tags: r

I am building a loop in an R script that calls the k.check() function. It was running perfectly, but now it isn't working anymore. When I call the k.check() function I get an error:

Error: could not find function "nearest"

This is weird to me since the function was working. First I thought, maybe I can find the function code online - that is how I got the code for k.check. I started my search and all I found were various self made "nearest" functions.

Next I thought, maybe I don't have a package activated. So, I started doing some digging for the package with the nearest function, and nadda. I finally found two packages that have a nearest function, but I didn't have them installed in my library. Thus, I had a feeling these weren't it. I gave them a shot anyway (sinkR and GenKern) and yes they didn't work. Then I just said to heck with it and activated all of my packages then ran the code. To my surprise, I got that error again

I did recently update some of my packages (I now am realizing was probably a bad idea), so now I am thinking that function was dropped or something. So now I stumped.

Does anyone have an idea what could be happening, what "nearest" function I need, and how I get it?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Where did you get it in the first place?

Comment: https://svn.r-project.org/R-packages/trunk/mgcv/R/plots.r

Comment: I found 3 `nearest` functions using `sos::findFn`. The one you didn't find is in a bioconductor package named IRanges

Comment: That is where I got the code for k.check

Comment: Thank you @BondedDust. I installed as instructed (http://www.bioconductor.org/install/) and retained IRanges but my code did not run. I still get the error that I am missing "nearest"

Comment: I'm not sure what "retained" means. The two functions that could load IRanges to an R session are `require` and `library`. Given that you never provided any code in your question, we don't even know if you effectively tested the other packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a Google advanced search limited to the site where you got that function, you will find that there is a nearest function defined in the `sparse.r` section of that version of mgcv: https://svn.r-project.org/R-packages/trunk/mgcv/R/sparse.r

```
nearest <- function(k,X,gt.zero = FALSE,get.a=FALSE) {
## The rows of X contain coordinates of points.
## For each point, this routine finds its k nearest 
## neighbours, returning a list of 2, n by k matrices:
## ni - ith row indexes the rows of X containing 
##      the k nearest neighbours of X[i,]
## dist - ith row is the distances to the k nearest 
##        neighbours.
## a - area associated with each point, if get.a is TRUE 
## ties are broken arbitrarily.
## gt.zero indicates that neighbours must have distances greater
## than zero...

  if (gt.zero) {
    Xu <- uniquecombs(X);ind <- attr(Xu,"index") ## Xu[ind,] == X
  } else { Xu <- X; ind <- 1:nrow(X)}
  if (k>nrow(Xu)) stop("not enough unique values to find k nearest")
  nobs <- length(ind)
  n <- nrow(Xu)
  d <- ncol(Xu)
  dist <- matrix(0,n,k)
  if (get.a) a <- 1:n else a=1

  oo <- .C(C_k_nn,Xu=as.double(Xu),dist=as.double(dist),a=as.double(a),ni=as.integer(dist),
                    n=as.integer(n),d=as.integer(d),k=as.integer(k),get.a=as.integer(get.a))

  dist <- matrix(oo$dist,n,k)[ind,]
  rind <- 1:nobs
  rind[ind] <- 1:nobs
  ni <- matrix(rind[oo$ni+1],n,k)[ind,]
  if (get.a) a=oo$a[ind] else a <- NULL
  list(ni=ni,dist=dist,a=a)
} # nearest
```

I also now find it (after updating to the most recent version of mgcv that is on CRAN) by typing the function name even without loading the package.

```
mgcv:::nearest
```

Whereass it is neither documented in the help files nor exported:

```
> mgcv::nearest
Error: 'nearest' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mgcv'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I gave the function a shot and I am getting a different error now: "Error in nearest(nn, as.matrix(dat)) : object 'C_k_nn' not found". I see where it is being called so I am going to do some digging and see what is happening, but this gets me where I need to be. Thank you again!